# Xcode Export Localizations for an iOS app using Swift Package Manager packages fails: No such module UIKit

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift-package-manager

I'm building an iOS app (the supported destinations in the app target are iOS, iPad and Mac - Designed for iPad). I've many SPM frameworks in order to split my codebase in different features. I want to export the localisations for the different packages and the app using Xcode but it fails. I followed the Apple guide regarding SPM localization: the packages contains a Resources folder with a folder for each language supported. I specified the platforms `.iOS(.v16)` in the packages. But it seems that exporting the localisations using the `Product > Export Localizations` feature in Xcode compiles also the packages and app for macOS. Here is the error message:

```
Showing Recent Messages

/Users/axel/Developer/AppName/Packages/Helpers/Sources/Helpers/UIKit/UIImage+Extension.swift:7:14:
No such module 'UIKit'

/Users/axel/Developer/AppName/Packages/Helpers/Sources/Helpers/UIKit/UIImage+Extension.swift:7:14:
UIKit is not available when building for macOS. Consider using `#if canImport(UIKit)` to conditionally import this framework.
```

Is there a way to have the export feature work when building an iOS app with packages specified for iOS?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

An Apple Frameworks Engineer answered on Apple Developer Forums:

> Unfortunately, this is a known limitation of exporting Swift packages
> for localization. In general, Swift packages aren’t able to restrict
> code to specific platforms (see discussion [here](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0236-package-manager-platform-deployment-settings.md#future-directions)). The platforms [key](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/packagedescription/supportedplatform) in
> the package manifest is used for setting a minimum deployment target,
> not declaring if a platform is supported. So you may need to
> conditionalize any iOS-specific API calls with compiler directives as
> the error suggests: UIKit is not available when building for macOS.
> Consider using `#if canImport(UIKit)` to conditionally import this
> framework